Reverse lookup for fields with choices in django models
I have following model :
class Role(models.Model) :
    class RoleTypes(models.TextChoices) :
        PAID = 'P', 'Paid'
        UNPAID = 'U', 'Unpaid'
        COLLABORATION = 'C', 'Collaboration'

   role_type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=RoleTypes.choices, default=RoleTypes.PAID)
   role_count = models.IntegerField(default = 1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)])

And following serializer :
class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta :
       model = Role
       fields = '__all__'

Now Role resource is created by passing following data in post request :
{'role_type':'P', 'role_count':2}

Is it possible that data sent in post request sets role_type = 'Paid' instead of 'P'

Why then not use PAID = 'Paid', 'Paid'? The data is essentially just the "id", something to uniqly identify the option.

But using the "label", that would be a bad idea, especially since the label is not per se a (real) string, it can be a safe string (mark_safe), or some other proxy object that generates html for example.


Is it possible that data sent in post request sets role_type = 'Paid' instead of 'P'.

You can set the "id" to:
class Role(models.Model):
    class RoleTypes(models.TextChoices):
        PAID = 'Paid', 'Paid'
        UNPAID = 'Unpaid', 'Unpaid'
        COLLABORATION = 'Collab', 'Collaboration'

    role_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=6, choices=RoleTypes.choices, default=RoleTypes.PAID
    )


# …
since this is the id of the option.
If you mean send the label, that would probably not be a good idea: the label is not per se a string, in fact it is often a lazy translatable string [Django-doc], so where the eventually string depends on the activated language, or a safe string (with mark_safe(…) [Django-doc]). This thus means that it is not even said that we can recuperate the label when the request was made, or check for equality.
While you probably can subclass the form field to look for the matching label, for good reasons it thus uses a more "stable" marker, P in the case you use PAID = 'P', 'Paid', or 'Paid' in case of PAID = 'Paid', 'Paid'. Using the label is not a good idea.
You should also consider exactly what is passed as request data more of an implementation detail, just like an AutoField happens to store data an integer, but adding two primary keys together makes no sense, so you should not go introspect the value.
